# Sometimes, the Bind9 will return the recursive record after I configure the response policy zone

Tags: bind, rpz

I configure a response policy zone in my DNS server and I use that to block two domains.
This is my zone file.

```
$TTL    1
$ORIGIN rpztest.
@       IN      SOA     ns1.fati. ns2.fati. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                          86400 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;    
                NS      ns1.fati.
                NS      ns2.fati.
; check dns connection
check.dns.tw.fullaccesstointernet.cn.eu.org     IN      A       103.61.139.106
*.check.dns.tw.fullaccesstointernet.cn.eu.org   IN      A       103.61.139.106
nekomoe.moe     IN      A       103.61.139.106
*.nekomoe.moe   IN      A       103.61.139.106
```

After configuring RPZ, sometimes it returns the record from the original authoritative name server. Looks like this picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsP6I.png)

This is my config file.

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        recursion yes;
        allow-recursion {any;};
        allow-query {any;};
        // max-cache-ttl 1;
        // max-ncache-ttl 1;
        response-policy {
                zone "rpztest";
        }
        qname-wait-recurse no;
        dnssec-validation auto;

        listen-on { any; };
};

zone "rpztest" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/response.policy.zone";
        allow-transfer {any;};
};
```

How can I solve this kind of problem?